# Copy select lines from many text files and paste to new file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to use it to do what I think should be a very simple task.  I have a folder with many .log files, which each have many lines of data.  I want to copy the lines which only contain a certain key word, and paste every line from each file in to one master file that I can open in excel.  I've been searching for an answer, and I just can't quite seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO :-) May I please suggest that you edit your post to include at least part of your attempt at a solution. Thank you for your consideration

Comment: Do you have any code so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Sorry for the uber-newguyness...  What I had that worked for one file is the following:

file('out.txt', 'w').writelines(l for l in file('20100210.LOG') if 'BRAC' in l)

But I have ~30 files I want to extract lines from to create a master file which I can open in Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you need. Put file with this code in the directory where you have your `.log` files, replace `KEYWORD` with what you are actually looking for, and run it.

```
import os
theKeyword = 'KEYWORD'
directory = '.' 
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file.endswith(".log"):
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if theKeyword in line:
                        out.write(line)
```

As suggested, you can use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) instead of [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
from glob import glob
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    for file in glob('*.log'):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if 'KEYWORD' in line:
                    out.write(line)
```

The code can be even a bit simpler if you use [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
from glob import glob
import fileinput
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    for line in fileinput.input(glob('*.log')):
        if 'KEYWORD' in line:
            out.write(line)
```

Another variation of the 'grep in Python' thing:

```
from glob import glob
import fileinput
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(line for line in fileinput.input(glob('*.log')) if 'KEYWORD' in line)
```

In the above snippet, if you remove `fileinput.input`'s argument, then it will process `sys.argv[1:]`, so you can run your script with file names as parameters.

In case you'd like to search for files recursively in subdirectories of a directory, you should have a look at [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) function.

If you have a Linux/Unix/Mac box, or if you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed on a Windows box, the same can be achieved a bit easier using shell tools:

```
$ cat *.log| grep KEYWORD >output.csv
```

Comment: And even better `for line in fileinput.input(glob('*.log'))`... (reduces indentation and helps readability IMHO)

Comment: @JonClements Nice! I didn't know that module. My Python is a bit rusty, I don't use it everyday...

Comment: And then finally, `out.writelines(line for line in fileinput.input(glob('*.log')) if 'keyword' in line)` :)

Comment: I was just going to change this like that myself, I swear! :-)

Comment: Awesome!!  The 3rd bit of code got me from 2.1 GB in ~30 files to one 130MB file.  Thanks!  Time to start spending more time teaching myself Python :-)

Comment: @MattLeonard Cool! I definitely recommend learning some Python - next time, when you have something slightly more difficult to do, you may have trouble finding peeps willing to do the job for you on SO ;-) BTW. Do you mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks piokuc.  I just started doing an MIT open course online.  But I agree with you, it isn't fair to have somebody do it for me.  However, it's nice to see how to do something correctly and learn from it.  Plus, now I can work from this base and keep adding to it.

Comment: No problem. Learn Python and have fun doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

outfile = open("outfile.txt", "w")
temp_list = []
for cur_file in os.listdir("."):
    if cur_file.endswith(".log"):
        for line in open(cur_file, "r").readlines():
            if "KEYWORD" in line:
                outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```